# jQuery regex help

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

I need some simple help with regex I want to grab the values in between brackets and equal signs.

```
<a href="[url=img.php?i=1][pod=2]">My Link</a>
```

then grab the values of **url** = **img.php?i=1** and **pod** = **2**

so somehow regex should check in between **[** and **=** then get the value in between **=** and **]**

Comment: Why do you have a link like this? This is not a valid URL.

Comment: of course its not a valid url, I will be doing things with these values in javascript, this has nothing to do with linking.

Comment: Then there might be a better solution for what you want to do. If someone disabled JS, whatever you want to do won't work and the link will be utterly useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try out this sample for yourself - http://jsfiddle.net/ENwf8/

```
var string = "[url=img.php?i=1][pod=2]";
var regEx = /\[(.*?)=(.*?)]\[(.*?)=(.*?)]/;
var matches = string .match(regEx);

for (index = 0; index < matches.length; index++) {
    document.write(index + ": " + matches[index] + "<br>");
}
```

prints:

```
0: [url=img.php?i=1][pod=2]
1: url
2: img.php?i=1
3: pod
4: 2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var matches = "<a href=\"[url=img.php?i=1][pod=2]\">My Link</a>".match(/\[url=(.*)]\[pod=(.*)\]">/);

var url = matches[1]; // == img.php?i=1
var pod = matches[2]; // == 2
```

There you go!